# How to import data using Sqoop from RDBMS into local file system, not HDFS?

Tags: file, import, local, rdbms, sqoop

I have seen Sqoop allows one to import data from an RDBMS database into HDFS. I however want to import data into **local file system folders** in Linux and NOT into HDFS file system.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sqoop1, you can use the "-fs" option as detailed in the [documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments). Here's a quick example:

```
sqoop import -fs local -jt local --connect jdbc:mysql://<host>/sqoop --username sqoop --password sqoop --table tbl
```

In Sqoop2, you will be able to [choose your file system](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1620) when creating a link:

```
HDFS URI: file:///
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the table in the directory from where sqoop it is invoked:

```
sqoop import -fs file:/// -jt local --connect jdbc://<host>/<database_name> --username <user_name> --password <password> --table <table_name>
```

the table will be stored as a csv file in ./